# Polymer and REST backend : how to keep fresh data

Tags: java, rest, polymer, data-synchronization

I've build a 'Polymer 1.X' web application that is retrieving data from my backend through REST calls. 
Once the pages are loaded for the first time, a call to the backend using 'iron-ajax'.

One example, a customer can see the availabilities of a provider. The provider can enter new things in his calendar. My problem is that the customers won't receive the update of the availabilities unless they explicitly refresh the pages or access it afterwards.

What are the good practices to keep relatively fresh data ?

Comment: You want to keep requesting the backend for data after init?
Checkout polymer async https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-async , you may call a async method on response to make it request again after a specified time. Quite straight forward solution to keep requesting data.

Comment: One way is you should make the REST calls again and again on specific time gap or use should keep the client and server in sync by implementing the real time functionalities in server.

Comment: @JonathanAndersson : isn't it a risk to overload the server for unuseful requests ? I guess I should select which requests are elegible for refresh. For example, user profile data refresh is useless.

Comment: @aries12 : do you have any hints on the proposed client/server sync real time functionalties ?

Comment: Not really.I have worked on similar kind of application where a patient books a slot and it should reflected in doctord UI.Have no idea of what is happening on the server side.

Comment: Use websockets to send a ping if a resource has changed. The clients that are looking at those providers will get notified of the change and send a "useful" request.